# Strange behavior leaflet when adding a marker

Tags: leaflet, marker

Working example: http://markercluster.meteor.com/

If you double click on the map to add a marker, then this place will be the upper left corner marker, not pin.
The coordinates of the mouse pointer and marker coordinates coincide: it can be seen in the browser console.

Actually the question: What am I doing wrong? How to make a marker added correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding option `iconAnchor`

**EDIT:**

```
myIcon = L.icon(
      iconUrl: "packages/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png"
      shadowUrl: "packages/leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png"
      iconAnchor: [12, 41] #[iconWidth/2, iconHeight]
    )
```

Comment: You might improve this answer by giving some code example.